# Exchange 2010 - Cannot Remove Auto Response

Tags: exchange-2010

My predecessor has setup an auto response on a users mailbox however it now needs removing and I cannot find where or how it is applied.

I would assume the best way to do it would be through Transport Rules. No transport rules are setup, there are no automatic replies and no inbox rules on that account.

I am certain there are no 3rd party tools installed that could accomplish this too.

Is there any other possible way this could have been setup?

*-Edit-*

Subject: This is an automated response.

Headers:

```
Received: from MAIL-01.lockings.co.uk ([::1]) by MAIL-01.lockings.co.uk
 ([::1]) with Microsoft SMTP Server id 14.03.0181.006; Mon, 28 Apr 2014
 12:24:28 +0100
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: Lisa <****@lockings.co.uk>
To: Matthew <****@lockings.co.uk>
Subject: This is an automated response.
Thread-Topic: This is an automated response.
Thread-Index: AQHPYtRr9zO5fconh0S+pGAsaMryKQ==
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-Auto-Response-Suppress: All
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: ****@lockings.co.uk
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: e804f606-7955-4433-af4e-af2606f40bb5
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Mon, 28 Apr 2014 12:24:28 +0100
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: MAIL-01.lockings.co.uk
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 03
Message-Id: <2d24bccd307143b7819c7cba253283db@MAIL-01.lockings.co.uk>
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: Kaspersk;1404280943;0;0
X-KSE-Antivirus-Interceptor-Info: scan successful
X-KSE-Antivirus-Info: Clean
```

Comment: What does the auto-response headers look like and the subject line exactly?  Edit your question with that info.

Answer (score 1):

This `"X-MS-Exchange-Inbox-Rules-Loop: ****@lockings.co.uk"`  Line says that it was Generated from a Outlook Rule. So there is a Rule in outlook that is generating the message.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say there's no auto-replies setup on the user, since you didn't explain how you determined that, I'd say try this:

- Open up Outlook Web Access.
- Open the target users mailbox (click your name, type in their user name, hit Open).
- Under *Options*, turn off the Automatic Replies.

Comment: I have tried both OWA and Outlook 2013 (using Full Access Permissions). And also through Exchange Powershell.